# Why have my copilot for CLI stopped working

Tags: github-copilot

I have been using copilot for CLI on MacOS for a while and it has been very nice. But now when I start a terminal session I get:

`.zshrc:151: command not found: github-copilot-cli`

In line 151 I have:

`eval "$(github-copilot-cli alias -- "$0")"`

I have tried to reinstall: `npm i @githubnext/github-copilot-cli` but that did not help.
Any idea why copilot CLI have stoped working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and for me  `npm install -g @githubnext/github-copilot-cli` followed by `github-copilot-cli auth` made the trick